# Restore from last hibernation state on reboot

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hibernate, restore

I restored my PC from hibernation earlier today.  10 minutes after booting, there was a power cut.   These things happen.

Is there any way to tell my PC on next boot to use the previous hibernation state to boot into?  Some motherboard setting or such?  I don't know how the machine determines to boot from scratch or from hibernation.  I know that hiberfil.sys gets left lying around after booting from hibernation but I don't know if it's reusable or not.  If it's not then I assume I'm definitely out of luck at that point.

From reading I suspect I might be out of luck, however I feel my question differs from the others on this subject because I'm not looking to set this up as a regular process.

I've not yet powered the machine in question back up yet, just in case there is a chance it can be restored.

My OS is Windows 8.1.
The motherboard is a RoG Maximus VI Hero.

**EDIT**
Whilst my question has been answered with confirmation that restoring a previous hibernation state does not appear to be possible, this question is not a duplicate of the ones highlighted in the comments; I'd already read those before I posted my own.

[842161](https://superuser.com/questions/842161) Refers to a different operating system (I've since added the Windows-8-1 tag) and also for a normal reboot through a Windows update, which could easily have made all sorts of changes.  My situation related to direct power loss barely 10 minutes after booting from hibernation (and thus, I would presume, minimal harddisk changes following the past hibernation).

[607300](https://superuser.com/questions/607300) Relates to an entirely different request where they appear to want to set up some sort of regular system that would be able to automatically save a state like with hibernation that can be restored from so that on sudden power loss they can jump right back to where they were.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/842161/how-can-i-restore-from-a-previous-hibernation-state and https://superuser.com/questions/607300/can-i-create-save-a-hibernation-state-to-recover-from-without-actually-hiberna

Comment: The first one is where Windows Update rebooted the machine rather than sudden power loss.  Windows Update could easily have affected the system such that restoring from old hibernation data is impossible.  The second one talks about it as a regular process, but with file changes on the disk and such from their usage, that could also make it impossible.  My machine was on for only 10 minutes and had made no deliberate file changes at that point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restore from a previous hibernation state?](https://superuser.com/questions/842161/how-can-i-restore-from-a-previous-hibernation-state)

Comment: @Moab I already explained in the comment directly above yours why [842161](https://superuser.com/questions/842161) is different from my question (the circumstances are entirely different).

Comment: Btw not a direct answer but other solutions exist for the power loss situation e.g. battery backups. Also backup supplies with snmp or other status output can trigger a smooth hibernate or shutdown on the machine when the battery is low. 

Although, personally, my problem is usually when I say, try to wake up my laptop without realizing that the charger isn't plugged in or something, and that last 1% in the battery only keeps it alive just long enough to load and invalidate the hibernate file... >:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible and in fact Windows has gone to considerable lengths to ensure it does not. And for good reason. Doing so would almost certainly result in some level of data corruption. The exact nature and extent of the corruption is unpredictable but you can be sure it would not be pleasant.

Early in the boot process Windows checks for a special signature in the hiberfil.sys file. If this signature is present and verified a restore from hibernation is started. If the signature is not present or in any way invalid a normal boot will begin. The details of how this works are undocumented. After the restore is completed the signature is invalidated. This is to ensure the current hiberfil.sys contents is used only once.

When the system is put in hibernation the system state in memory is saved to hiberfil.sys so it can later be restored. But the hiberfil.sys file does not contain the entire system state. The state is also in the pagefile, the registry, and your data files on disk. The memory contents in hiberfil.sys contains portions of these and all must be 100% consistent with each other or the restored state would be corrupt. This would happen be the inevitable result if a previous hiberfil.sys contents were used. For that reason it is not allowed.

Comment: I fear you're right, and you've provided a solid explaination for why it's not workable, although I don't suppose you have any sources for this do you?  I'm not doubting you, it's more that it would be both useful and interesting to be able to read further into this.

Comment: @Interminable I had the same question as you and this answer also convinced me it wasn't possible. But to answer (but not really, lol) your comment question: I don't know of any sources but you can deduce most of the issues like this: 1) the hibernate state file only stores state that wouldn't survive power off (memory, registers, keyboard toggles like caps lock, etc.), therefore 2) anything that is *normally* persistent (esp. hard drive data but also hardware configuration, etc.) would be assumed to be consistent with the hibernate state on wake up. Then, "normally persistent" has two...

Comment: ... categories: a) things you can control without power (like hardware) and b) things you can can't control at all. (A) isn't interesting; no surprise if you hibernate, removed some RAM, then the machine wakes up grumpy. But (B) will sneak up on you, so think of (B) examples and you can start imagining problems. E.g. wake up the machine, some program's in the middle of reading memory. Later, the page file contents change, as they do. Now you use the same hibernate state, same program in the middle of reading memory except now the content is different and it crashes. Etc.

Comment: I bet there's security risks too. I'm not an expert here but people are smart and it wouldn't be surprising if somebody came up with a way to manipulate the machine in such a way as to coerce e.g. virtualized (in page file) protected mode memory contents into paged locations that were publicly accessible when the hibernate state was created (if somebody knows the swap algorithm well enough they might be able to predict / control where things will end up), reuse the hibernate state with this rearranged page file, and grab sensitive info which is no longer in a sandboxed place. Or whatever.

Comment: A way comes to mind: test: hibernate system, boot linux and copy the pagefile somewhere. reboot windows... it should resume where you left it... work 5 minutes then reboot linux and copy back the hibernation file.. if that works then there might be a way.